# Creating NFC based parking lot app

Tags: android, dictionary, parking

I'm in progress of creating NFC based app for parking lot solution. So basically when user taps their NFC enabled phone to the tag, they'll be shown a map of the parking lot.
From there, user will be able to tap into one of the empty parking spots.
When user arrives at the location, they have to tap their smartphone to another tag, confirming their location.

Currently, I'm having trouble with displaying the map. Should I use Google Map and get the lat and long of the parking lot (it's outdoor) or is there any other method of displaying it? Such as maybe using a picture?

Addition : There will be several parking areas, such as A, B, C parking and several slots too. So when user taps parking area A, user will be given an animation of zooming in to parking lot A and new image will be displayed showing the overview of area A.

When user taps the empty slot, that slot will be reserved (still not going here yet, having confusion with showing map image)

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps Android SDK is your best option.. if you have an accurate sketch of the parking lot you use as a custom tile in the map

Comment: I've just looked up on the custom tile provider. Do I have to make a new Java class for the custom tile itself or just create it within the main activity in the app?
And does custom tile overlap with the Google Map tile?

Comment: I'm guessing Ground Overlays will be better for you but I can't really know from the info here so judge for yourself (See: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/groundoverlay)

Comment: I almost forgot.. and yes, the tiles will be placed above the google maps tile.. you can also hide the google maps tiles completely if you want. If you don't really need the mapping data and don't mind developing the map the gestures and etc you can also use a picture and do everything on you own

Comment: I think I won't be using ground overlay as I don't think it'd be suitable.. After some more research, I think I should use a custom overview image of the parking lot instead.. Oh and by the way, I forgot to add new information in the post regarding the parking slots and area, I'm adding it now

Comment: Ahh I've just read your new comment after I refreshed the page. Yes I realized that developing the gestures will be quite a hassle as there are several gestures which I will have to develop (pinch zoom, pinch rotate, and panning), so I might use Google map and overlay it with my own tile, then hide the Google maps tile.

Comment: You can first try to work with a library to provide an imageview with all the gestures and then avoid the maps sdk.. But I think you will enjoy the maps sdk a lot if you don't mind the Google copyright display on the screen

Comment: Exactly what I was having trouble with yesterday.. A bit.. Eye catching but not in a good way lol. I'm currently testing out the image I obtained, will update after getting some results